# Is it possible to create 404 error pages for specific subdiretories?

Tags: html, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, subdirectory

Is it possible to make custom 404 pages for specific subdirectories instead of having a global one?

eg I want

/bla to show /404.html

and /subdirectory/bla to show /subdirectory/404.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
ErrorDocument 404 /subdirectory/404.html
```

Comment: if I put that into .htaccess wont that make /bla go to /subdirectory/404.html too?

Comment: please select answer as correct answer, you can also vote up by clicking up arrow to appreciate answer